# random sampling of the data in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataframe with several columns and I need to re-sample from that data with more weight to one category. I think `np.random.choice` should work but not sure how to implement it. Following is the example data from which I want to sample randomly but want 70% probability of getting expensive home (based on the Expensive_home column, value = 1) and 30% probability for Expensive_home=0. How can I create the re-sampled data file? Thank you!

```
ID  Lot_Area    Year_Built  Full_Bath   Bedroom Sale_Price  Expensive_home
1   31770   1960    1   3   215000  0
2   11622   1961    1   2   105000  0
3   5389    1995    2   2   236500  0
4   8402    1998    2   3   180400  0
5   10176   1990    1   2   171500  0
6   6820    1985    1   1   212000  0
7   53504   2003    3   4   538000  1
8   12134   1988    2   4   164000  0
9   11394   2010    1   1   394432  1
10  19138   1951    1   2   141000  0
11  13175   1978    2   3   210000  0
12  11751   1977    2   3   190000  0
13  10625   1974    2   3   170000  0
14  7500    2000    2   3   216000  0
15  11241   1970    1   2   149000  0
16  2280    1978    2   3   146000  0
17  12858   2009    2   3   376162  1
18  12883   2009    2   3   290941  0
19  12182   2005    2   3   220000  0
20  11520   2005    2   3   275000  0
```

similar data file but with more of randomly picked 1s in the last column

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you might be able to use `df.sample` with a `weights` arguments, eg: `df.sample(n, weights=df['Expensive_home'].replace({0:0.3, 1:0.7}))` - not going to make that an answer at the moment though as not sure if that gives you the results you want... (you might have to do something different to provide it the weights that gives the desired result)

Comment: Thank you, I want a data frame with same number of cases and same columns just want more of the rows with 1s in the last column.

Comment: So what if you specify the sample size as the number of rows and pass `replace=True` so it can select the same row more than once, eg: `df.sample(len(df), replace=True, weights=df['Expensive_home'].replace({0:0.3, 1:0.7}))` - is that (close to) what you want?

Comment: Okay... and have you tried the line of code I posted above that should work fine on your dataframe?

Comment: Hi Jon - how would the code change if I want to under sample cases with 0s? Keep all the cases with Expensive_home=1 and random sample 30% of cases with Expensive_home=0 (of course without replacement). So my data will have fewer rows than total (20) cases. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Well... if you split the DF into expensive/non-expensive, then do a `non_expensive.sample(frac=0.3)` and append it to the expensive?

Comment: I've added an answer with both approaches

Answer (score 1):

To create a dataframe of the same length but allowing expensive to have a higher chance of being selected and allowing replacements, use:

```
weights = df['Expensive_home'].replace({0: 30, 1: 70})
df1 = df.sample(len(df), replace=True, weights=weights)
```

To create a dataframe with all expensive and then 30% of non-expensive, you can do:

```
expensive = df['Expensive_home'].astype(bool)
df2 = pd.concat([df[expensive], df[~expensive].sample(frac=0.3)])
```

Comment: Perfect, appreciate it. Thanks